# Reuse View for different Controllers Best way

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib

I have 3 custom View Controllers having almost similar design.
How can I create a view (in Storyboard or using XIB) so that I can use the same view for my 3 View Controllers?

Comment: Without looking at the view it is hard to make a decision, sometimes we uses UIStackView to keep the views varying and display one or two of them based on need and hide rest.

Comment: The standard approach is to create a Class extending UIView with Xib file. And call the same UIView class from 3 different VC's.

Comment: @Imad So basically I have to create a xib for UIView and assign that view as my base UIViewcontroller view.And implement user actions in the view using delegate.Is that your point?

Comment: There are two ways to do it, one using Base View Controller (which is having nib file for the common view) and inheriting the BaseVC in your VC's. Second is creating a separate UIView custom class with Nib and calling the same from 3 diff VC's. For me, the 1st approach is more productive.

Answer (score 3):

Make custom view with xib add common design that all 3 view controller.
Now add UIView in that view controller and give super class of that UIView to that custom class and this way you can use this custom view on 3 controller

See this i have use same view in multiple controller

[image]

Comment: You should fix your ambiguous constraints mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

/*******************/
**Method 1:**
create a class Base of type `UIViewController`, implement all design here.

Next Create class A of type Class Base.
Next Again, Create class B of type Class Base.
Next Again, Create class C of type Class Base.
 this is called sub Classing.

**Method 2:**

use All different ViewController. if you have any UIView Similar for all viewControllers, create its different Class and Allocate its object from each class. then use delegates And block to perform operations between UIViewControllers and UIView class.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and created a Github repo to solve it:
https://github.com/MaherKSantina/MSAutoView

Steps:

- Download repo
- Create a xib (ex: ListingView)
- Create a class (should be the same name as xib)
- Make the class inherit from MSAutoView
- Set the class name in the Identity inspector of the xib to the class's name (Make sure you select the File's Owner in xib before changing the class)
- Add a UIView to the storyboard
- Assign its class to the one you created
- The view should render the content of the xib

Detailed steps are available in the Readme of the repo.

Cheers